# Developing or implementing manual/advanced irrigation in SWAT+

Tags: hydrology, models

[image: error image attached]

The following error about HRU occurred when I was trying to implement manual (advanced) irrigation operation.

An additional message advises that I contact developers directly when you want to create an advanced irrigation schedule. I have done that but the responses take long. Is there anyone out there who has resolved the problem-please assist.